# How to use bounds within constructor

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I am creating a view via constructor for my collectionViewCell class. But I cannot use bounds property within it, but in a function, I can use it, which I don't wanna use because I have to modify my constructor properties accordingly where I'm rendering my cells. Here is the code of what I've done -

```
let customView:UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20,
                                    y: 20,
                                    width: bounds.width - 40,
                                    height: 100))
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    return view
}()
```

Here I get the bounds error -

> Instance member 'bounds' cannot be used on type 'CustomCollectionViewCell'

I don't know what's wrong with this or with my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `lazy` keyword to access self instances

```
lazy var customView:UIView = {
     let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20,
                                y: 20,
                                width: bounds.width - 40,
                                height: 100))
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    return view
}()
```

Marking your property as `lazy` tells the compiler not to allocate memory for that property until the first time it is actually called at run time. This is why you can access `self` inside your closure -- since this is a lazy variable, it is guaranteed that `self` is completely initialized by the time your closure is executed, and you access `self.bounds`.

Comment: One more Question, Do I have to use lazy var with every constructor?

Comment: No , only if you have to like what you encountered

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bounds because at that stage your super view is not being initialised yet and therefore has no frame or bounds. You need to change the frame of the `customView` at appropriate time. For example in `layoutSubviews`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
     customView.frame =  CGRect(
           x: 20,
           y: 20,
           width: bounds.width - 40,
           height: 100
     )

}
```

If you sure that your view will have a proper size at `init(frame: CGRect)` you can add the frame related code in initialization.

Comment: I have not tried your method but @Sh_Khan 's answer did the job for me. I hope that's the correct approach. Anyway thanks buddy!

Comment: Yeah, his solution is a top notch in this case, cheers.